# Dynamic reference to resouce id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable called `cognito_user_pool` and two resurces defined. `aws_cognito_identity_pool` requires the instance ID of `aws_cognito_user_pool_client` in the `client_id` parameter. The ID is accessed by `aws_cognito_user_pool_client.MY_CLIENT_NAME.id`, but the problem is that the client name is saved in the `cognito_user_pool` variable.

My question is how I can get the ID without hardcoding the client name.

The following setup does not work:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "example" {
  name         = var.cognito_user_pool
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id
}

resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool" "main" {
  identity_pool_name               = var.cognito_user_pool
  allow_unauthenticated_identities = false

  cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id               = aws_cognito_user_pool_client[var.cognito_user_pool].id
    provider_name           = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.endpoint
    server_side_token_check = false
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
Error: Invalid reference

  on setup.tf line 26, in resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool" "main":
  26:     client_id               = aws_cognito_user_pool_client[var.cognito_user_pool]

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the client name and client id isn't the same. If it were the same then you could just use the variable.

I believe the issue is that you are accessing / referencing the client id incorrectly.

The `cognito_identity_providers` block within `resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool" "main"` should be:

```
  cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id               = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.example.id
    provider_name           = aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.endpoint
    server_side_token_check = false
  }
```

Comment: I think I had one of those nights where it would have been better to just go to sleep and try again next day. Absolutely, I see what you mean now. Thanks man!